# Maneras de aplicar Bucles

Tags: java, bucle-for, bucles

Buen día!

Estoy empezando a conocer el mundo de Java, pero estando haciendo un ejercicio me salio una duda, el ejercicio fue el siguiente:

Realiza la siguiente serie numerica utilizando las estructuras repetitivas For, while y do-while:

°1, 99, 2, 98, 3, 97, 4, 96, 5, 95

Entonces escribi el codigo y todo bien pero mi pregunta es, hay alguna manera de que un numero siga imprimiendo su serie como tal, pero que el otro numero se detenga, es decir, en el **while**o en el **do-while** se escribe hasta donde debe de llegar un solo numero y casi al final del mismo código se le dice que vaya en decremento el otro y por ende, ambos terminan "igual", o después de los mismos ciclos . Pero digamos que yo quisiera que la serie fuera la siguiente:

**1** , 99, **2** , 98, **3** , 97, **4** , 96, **5** , 95, 94, 93, 92, 91.

Pense que quizá anidando un **if else**, pero no se si esa es la solución correcta o es mas complicado.

**Gracias**

Edit:

```
    public class CicloDos{
     public static void main(String args[]){

   int i = 1, j = 99;

   System.out.println("Serie con for: ");

   for(i = 1; i <= 5; i++){
    if( i < 5){
     System.out.print(i + ", ");
     System.out.print(j + ", ");
   } else{
     System.out.print(i + ", " );
     System.out.print(j + ".");
   }
    j--;
  }
   System.out.println("");
   i = 1;
   j = 99;
   System.out.println("");

   System.out.println("Serie con while: ");
   while(i <= 5){
    if( i < 5){
     System.out.print(i + ", ");
     System.out.print(j + ", ");
   } else{
     System.out.print(i + ", " );
     System.out.print(j +".");
   }
    i++;
    j--;
  }
   System.out.println("");
   i = 1;
   j = 99;
   System.out.println("");

   System.out.println("Serie con do-while");
   do{
    if( i < 5){
     System.out.print(i + ", ");
     System.out.print(j + ", ");
   } else {
     System.out.print(i + ", " );
     System.out.print(j +".");
   }
    i++;
    j--;
   } while( i <= 5);
 }
}
```

Comment: Usa dos variables, una que incremente y otra que decremente, y dentro del bucle muestra las dos y actualizalas.

Comment: Lo hice, pero pasa que tienen que terminar los mismos ciclos del bucle para terminar la condición. Y muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder c:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Claro que se pude hacer cualquiera de los 3 tipos de estructuras repetitivas. Lo único que tienes que hacer para decidir cual usar es saber la condición que vas a utilizar para la estructura. En programación no hay una única manera de resolver un problema si no muchas. Puedes utilizar cualquiera de las 3 estructuras y puedes utilizar la condición que mejor se adapte a tu código

**Ten en cuenta esto:**

- El For se ultiza principalmente cuando conoces el numero de veces que quieres que algo se ejecute; como decir quiero que se imprima mi nombre 5 veces
- El while lo utilizamos principalmente cuando no conoces el numero de veces que queremos que algo se ejecute; Como decir quiero que imprima mi nombre hasta que el usuario le indique al programa que ya no imprima más.

Un ejemplo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int sumar = 1;
    int restar = 99;

    while(restar > 0){ //Condicion
        System.out.print(sumar +  ", " + restar + ", ");
        sumar++;
        restar--;   
    }


}
```

El resultado es: 1, 99, 2, 98, 3, 97, 4, 96, 5, 95, 6, 94, 7, 93, 8, 92, 9, 91, 10..................98, 2, 99, 1,

**Explicacion:**
En este ejemplo creamos dos varibales que almacenan el  valor entero 1 y 99. Utilic-e un while por que es más fácil indicarle que quiero que se imprima hasta que "restar" sea mayor a 1 (o bien puedo usar "<= 0"); si hubiera usado un ciclo for tendría que indicarle la cantidad de veces que quiero que se repita el ciclo con un valor "i = 99". imprimo el valor que tienen la variables y luego le sumo 1 (++) y resto 1 (--) y se vuelve a repetir el numero de veces que sea necesario hasta que restar deje de ser mayor a 1; y se sale del ciclo.
* Complejidad: O(n)

La versatilidad que nos da el while es que nos permite en este caso jugar con el programa y decirle que quiero que se haga hasta que un valor sea igual a 50 o mayor a 0 o menor a 1,000 cambiando solo la condicion, mientras que con el for tendría que calcular la cantidad exacta de veces que quiero que se cicle.

- Dato interesante: el ciclo while puede representar cualquier estructura repetitiva si lo sabes usar correctamente

Espero que esto te haya ayudado a aclarar tus dudas y espero que sigas aprendiendo mucho más sobre Java.

- si eres nuevo en la programación ten en cuenta que no hay una sola manera de resolver un problema, sino montones de formas diferentes

Comment: Entiendo la explicación pero seguiría teniendo el mismo detalle, por que en el while, la condicion es para ambas variables o eso tengo entendido, es decir, mientras uno va en decremento el otro va en incremento, pero, si le digo al while la condición de que se detenga cuando una variable llega a x #, la otra por ende se detienen por que ambas obedecen al mismo ciclado, no? Por que no se si esto es valido 
```
while ( a <=10 && b >=90){
```
Muchísimas gracias por tu explicación tan detalla, y la verdad es que apenas estoy por mi cuenta, los ejercicios los saco de un cuaderno de un amigo xD

Comment: no necesariamente la condición del while tiene que involucrar ambas varibales, lo podrías llegar a utilizar si quisieras hacer casos más especificos. En el caso del principio funciona sin problema con "variable llega a x#", pero si quisieramos hacer algo mas especifico como, while ( a <=10 && b >=90) eso significa que se va a sumar y restar en 1, mientras el valor a sea menor o igual a 10 Y(AND) b mayor o igual a 90, por lo que el while se detendría cuando AMBAS variables se salga de ese rango de valores. Espero haber aclarado tus dudas, de no ser así coméntame tus dudad.  Yo encantado.

Comment: Quiero mencionarte rápida mente que la solución de "Jean Pierre" no es la mejor, por que involucra un while(true), como consejo de programador a programador evita utilizar los while true por que eso signica que el programa se va ejecutar infinitamente, pudiendo dar como resultado un stackoverflow (de ahi viene el nombre de esta página). No es que esté incorrecto, simplemente no es una buena práctica y menos para alguien que está comenzando. Cabe mencionar que una buena práctica para un programador es escribir código limpio y fácil de entender. Espero que te ayuden estos consejos

Comment: Uff... men, la verdad es que muchas gracias por las explicaciones tan detalladas, si hubiera más gente así ayudando el mundo sería otra cosa! Y tendré muy en cuenta tus consejo,  aún no entendía que por que el true, pero después de investigar ya me doy una idea.

Comment: Muchas gracias, amigo, por el comentario :) Espero que aprendas mucho y encuentres un amor y una pasión en la programación.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo haces con condiciones no va a estar mal, pero si el ejercicio es solo con ciclos, intenta esto:

```
    int incre=0;
    int decre=100;


    while(incre<100 && decre>0){
        incre++;
        System.out.println(incre);

        decre--;
        System.out.println(decre);
    }
```

---

con el do-while sería algo muy parecido:

```
    int incre=0;
    int decre=100;


    do{
        incre++;
        System.out.println(incre);

        decre--;
        System.out.println(decre);
    }while(incre<100 && decre>0);
```

Este código nos imprimirá lo que quieres, no se si sea lo que estas buscando, espero y sea de ayuda la respuesta.

Comment: No se como anexar lo que llevo de código en los comentarios, creo seria mas fácil de explicar, pero el problema es que creo que igual va haciendo los mismos ciclos, es decir mientras uno sube, el otro baja (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6... y el otro seria asi 100, 99, 98, 97, 96...)  y lo que busco es que mientras una variable se detiene digamos, la variable de aumento se detiene en 25, la variable de decremento siga de 100 a 0. Y muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para responder c:

Comment: muy difícil entender, si quieres edita la publicación y con Ctrl+K, te sale apartado para insertar código. Lo que intentas hacer es muy raro, a lo mejor lo que necesites son 2 ciclos anidados.

Comment: ¡Oh lo logre! ¡muchas gracias! Desde que hice la pregunta lo intente como dice del lado derecho pero no me salia :c.

Espero sea mas facil de comprenderme :c, pondre en practica la idea de los ciclos anidados, utilizando condicionantes diferentes, no solo una y que de ahi se rija toda el ciclo. Gracias :D

Comment: jaja, los else en todos los ciclos sobran, ya que siempre va ser menor, aunque así estas es dando nuevo valor a la variable no se detienen cuando la de aumento sea 25, pero felicidades...

Comment: Jaja es que los puse por que el profe requería que tras cada numero saliera una coma y que el ultimo numero de la seria saliera con un punto jajaja y no encontraba otra manera de que así fuera :p, ¡Muchas gracias por detenerte a leer mi pregunta y por la ayuda!

Answer (score 0):

Claro que se puede, tu código deberia tener algo como esto:

```
int contador1 = 0;
int contador2 = 100;
String output = ""; 

while(true){
        contador1++;
        contador2--;
        if(contador1 <= 5){
          if (contador1 == 1){
            output = "" + (contador1);
          }else{
            output += ", " + (contador1);
          }
        }

        output += ", " + (contador2);

        if (contador2 == 91){ 
            output += ".";
            break; //este break es para salir del ciclo 
        }
}

System.out.println(output);
```

Comment: ooooooooh, entonces si es anidando los if, Muchas gracias! :D